# get active page name in ionic2 with angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I trying to get the name of the current page in ionic2. When the page loads i get this error

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

JS

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public http: Http) {
                //this.navCtrl.push(AccountPage)
                console.log(this.navCtrl.getActive().name); 

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
      console.log(this.navCtrl.getActive().name);
  }
```